# CSS3 select remainder at end of list

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to know if there is any way to select the remainder of a list using CSS selectors.  As an example:

Say I have a list of unknown length, but the number of elements I would like to display in each grouping (n) is known, but variable.
For all elements, I would like to add margin-bottom, except for the remainder elements that come after the last complete grouping.  This list is unknown length until time of render, so I am looking for a pure css method.

I am convinced this would be a challenging problem, a hard coded solution will not work because the number in each grouping is a variable.

I know it seems simple, but I have not found a combination of nth-child(), not(), ~, etc. that can achieve this.  Furthermore, if I change the parameter for number of elements per row from 3 to 5, for example, the last 4 elements are what I would want to select.

Edit2:
Sorry, I really should have clarified. I am using React/Redux framework and writing JavaScript and styled-components, but that being said:

As far as I am aware, I have no way of applying classes that would help separate this list AT ALL. I cannot group them into rows with classes, and furthermore I should add that for all intents and purposes, I am looking for a solution that uses only index logic.

My only hunch so far would be if I can figure out a way to pass the length of the list, and thereby calculate the remainder, but the length is unknown until the time of render.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nth-child()` selector

at your case:

```
 li:nth-child(13) {

}

 li:nth-child(14) {

}
```

Check this link for more details https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

If you're interesting in selecting the last element of the list (or any that comes before it) you can use the `:nth-last-child()` selector

Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I am not looking for a hard-coded solution, I have access to the number of elements to be displayed in each row.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the last 3 li of the list.

`li:nth-last-child(-n+3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
.container:not(:last-child) .element {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Where `.container` is the container around all the rows, and `.element` is the individual numbered item
(13 + 14 in your example)